# WebSocket: onMessage() only triggered at the end when server is closing connection

Tags: javascript, windows, websocket

I have a weird error that I can not solve.

My implementation WebSocket works perfectly. The browser connects to the server, exchange their keys and the connection is fully established! The server starts sending messages to clients (visible in the network traffic).

But on my PC, all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, portable or not), the "onMessage ()" is correctly interpreted ... but only at the end when I turn off the server! In other words, if I put an alert () to each onMessage (), during exchange, I did absolutely nothing. But once I cut the server, I receive all alerts at once!

Yet on my MacBook everything works perfectly.

This ironic is it that behavior that affects all of my browsers on my PC. I run under Windows 7.

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Are you using a standard server or did you write your own?  If its your own server, it'd be interesting to see your code.  Also, do the browser onOpen callbacks run when the handshake completes or only on shutdown too?

Comment: I use my own server, but i've tested with an online echo test, the message is sent, but nothing returns. The message is only returned when i disable network interface.
Yep, onOpen works perfectly and alert() is called successfully when connection is etablished. Just onMessage() is doing the mess.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the issue !

If you have some troubles with Websockets, just **disable the SSDP discover service** on Windows.

```
net stop SSDPSRV
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue recently. web server runs a separate SSDP discovery process to find uPnP devices on the network. When I had SSDP enabled, my websocket connection was always closed. Disabling SSDP solved it. But I haven't had a chance to investigate *why*.